# Extract a specific string inbetween strings by regex

Tags: regex

I have a url like this

```
  http://localhost:4970/eagle
&Account=001
&FruitSlad=Apple, Rambutab
 &Fruits=Canada
```

and I want to extract the text between  FruitSlad and the next & and I tried to write a regex for it 
I tried ((GroupByMultiples)(.$&?)) but it didnt work .  Um seeking for a help to extract the text between &FruitSlad and the next &

Comment: post the expected output..

Comment: you mean this `(?<=&FruitSlad=)[^&\n]*` or `(?<=&FruitSlad=).*`

Comment: expected output is Apple,rambutan

Comment: @kirov which language, to know wich interpreter and see if you need capture groups or not, etc.

Comment: its working for Javascript and Python @AvinashRaj thank you

Comment: it won't work for js but it do work for python..

Comment: Let me check again . i wont to use with js

Comment: @AvinashRaj it works for JS smoothly , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/FruitSlad=([^&]+)/
```

[See here](http://regexr.com/39poq).

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you could do the following.

```
var url = "\
  http://localhost:4970/eagle \
&Account=001 \
&FruitSlad=Apple, Rambutab \
 &Fruits=Canada";

var result = url.split('&')[2].split('=')[1];
console.log(result.trim()); //=> "Apple, Rambutab"
```

Or if you prefer using regex ...

```
var result = url.match(/&FruitSlad=([^&]+)/);
if (result)
    console.log(result[1].trim()); //=> "Apple, Rambutab"
```

Answer (score 1):

The convenient way to get values of query variables in Python 2.x is to use [urlparse module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse):

```
import urlparse

url = 'http://localhost:4970/eagle?Account=001&FruitSlad=Apple, Rambutab&Fruits=Canada'
vars = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)
print vars['FruitSlad'][0]
```

In Python 3.x use [urllib.parse module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse):

```
import urllib.parse

url = 'http://localhost:4970/eagle?Account=001&FruitSlad=Apple, Rambutab&Fruits=Canada'
vars = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query)
print(vars['FruitSlad'][0])
```

This module decodes also various encoded characters (*`%nn`*), so is more suitable than regex in this case.